# Successfully Setting a MSSQL Database value to NULL

Tags: php, sql-server, null

I have a query (insecure for the minute) that attempts to set a value of a column to NULL. Basically just revert it to being empty. 'Allow NULL' is checked in the Database design. Its an MSSQL Database. First of all I tried:

```
$query = "UPDATE  Table_Name SET Image = '', Thumb = '' WHERE PageID = 5";
```

Then:

```
$query = "UPDATE  Table_Name SET Image = NULL, Thumb = NULL WHERE PageID = 5";
```

The second one produces no errors, but does not set the database value to NULL. From what I can see though (website research) 'NULL' is correct? Sorry, new to PHP.

**EDIT**

The query is called by an if statement. That checks to see if a GET value is equal to. I am aware that this isn't very secure. I am just trying to test/play a little with techniques. The full call and query are as follows.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['change']) && $_GET['change'] == "image1") {
    $query = "UPDATE  Table_Name SET Image = NULL, Thumb = NULL WHERE     NewsID = ".$_GET['id']." ";
}
?>
```

This if statement is triggered a delete 'button'. The code looks like:

```
<a href="Update.php?change=image1&cid=<?php echo $row["NewsID"]; ?>&id=<?php echo $row["NewsID"]; ?>">delete</a></td>
```

I now believe, the query isn't getting called? However the button does change and set the values it is meant to do, so all I can assume, is that the if statement doesn't pick up on this. Update.php is the page the queries are currently on so it almost just acts as a refresh.

Comment: The second statement is just fine.

Comment: The code you posted just assigns a string literal to a variable. Are you actually executing the query? Can you post the code where you do that?

Comment: Using Management Studio?  Maybe the issue is where you are viewing the data you are not seeing them as 'NULL'?  Test with `SELECT * FROM Table_Name WHERE Thumb IS NULL`

Comment: Yes, just tried your suggestion though and it still showed ID 5 as not NULL. ie had an entry. Testing if the query is actually getting called, but receive no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used PHP in a very long time, but does NULL need to be enclosed in quotes?

Try this:

```
$query = "UPDATE  Table_Name SET Image = 'NULL', Thumb = 'NULL' WHERE PageID = 5";
```

Hope this helps.